# Convert between different wave formats (WAVEFORMATEX)

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, wasapi

I'm writing a real-time audio application that runs a stream in exclusive mode.  In order to properly present data to the device, it needs to arrive in a format that isn't of my own choosing.  All of my audio processing is done with floating point samples before being sent to the device, and the device's wave format might not be (and probably isn't) set to `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT` - for example, it might be `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` or `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM`.

Is there an API that makes it easy to convert between one wave format (floating point) and another (the device's format)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Audio Compression Manager (ACM) conversion stream:

[Converting Data from One Format to Another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797805.aspx)

If you cannot create a single stream from your format to the device's format, you will have to create two streams - one from your format to `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM`, and the other from `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM` to the device's format (all streams/devices have to support conversions to/from PCM).